# Batch marking 'not a duplicate'

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Just wondering if it's possible to batch mark multiple contacts as 'Not a duplicate' through the dedupe rule menu. I've tried selecting all the contacts via the checkmark and using 'not a duplicate' but this only marks the first one as not a duplicate. It's restricting workflow at the moment due to the amount of non-duplicates my organisation is getting.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. I don't think there is.

Comment: I need the same here...would be nice to have that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported within the core dedupe screen but it does appear that the [Deduper extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/deduper/en/latest/) offers this:

[image]

You can [raise an issue here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues) for a feature improvement. It is a gap since batch processes for all other actions are possible on the dedupe screen.